# Change from UID to ANR in LDAP query?

Tags: security, active-directory, azure-active-directory, ldap, apache2

I have secured a website using Apache2 HTTPD with LDAP mod with the following config. It works great for almost everyone, however for 2 users it returns an "<user> not found" error.

Our security team has indicated that we should try changing from checking the UID to instead check the ANR.

I have googled, but can't find much information on ANR. What is ANR? How do I switch to use ANR?

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName mydomain
    Redirect permanent / https://mydomain/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/mydomain.key
    ProxyPreserveHost on
    ProxyRequests off
    ServerName mydomain
    ProxyPass / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://0.0.0.0:8080/
    <Proxy *>
        AuthType Basic
        Authname "Password Required"
        AuthBasicProvider ldap
        AuthLDAPURL ldaps://realm.domain.local:3269
        #AuthLDAPCompareAsUser on
        #LDAPReferrals off
        AuthLDAPBindDN "CN=SVC-Auth,OU=ServiceAccounts,DC=<domain>,DC=local"
        AuthLDAPBindPassword "<password>"
        Require valid-user
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

How is it possible for this to work great for the majority of users, but for the user to be missing for a small subset of users? These users can login fine to all other AD services.

Comment: I've only been using LDAP for 12 years but I have never heard of ANR, and I'm not aware of any way to check it with Apache HTTPD. And there is no UID checking here. Ask the people who gave you this advice what they are talking about. Off topic. But this is Apache HTTPD, not 'Apache2 LDAP'.

Comment: Edited to be more clear its HTTPD with LDAP mod.

Comment: ANR is a filter rewrite occuring on the server side. Basically, when a client use a filter `anr=something` in a search request, AD notices it and rewrite the filter according to the schema (to which objects have ANR and SEARCH index set), which for example can result in `(|(uid=something)(cn=something))`. The problem is that it may bring you more result than you want.

Comment: I think this is not the issue here. The first thing is that you should provide a search filter in AuthLDAPURL, eg. filtering explicitly on the uid attribute, assuming the users to authenticate are under ou=Users : `ldaps://realm.domain.local:3269/OU=Users,DC=<domain>,DC=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)`

Comment: Our AD team just informed me that not all users have a UID which is why its failing for a small subset of users. I just don't know how to switch it to use ANR in my Apache configuration.

Comment: Before switching to ANR queries (which no one here seems to be familiar to), I strongly suggest you try to use an explicit filter. There should be some attributes other than uid that are (should) guaranteed unique in AD, such as `samaccountname`, `userprincipalname`, possibly `cn`...

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use a specific filter, for example on samaccountname? Do I simply add it to the AuthLDAPBindDN or do I append it to AuthLDAPURL?

Comment: I already provided an AuthLDAPURL example with uid. Just replace `uid` with the unique attribute to use (your AD team should know which one, if not, try with `anr`). AuthLDAPBindDN is the dn used by httpd to bind to the server, then it takes the AuthLDAPURL to search and authenticate user if it matches the request, so the filter goes in AuthLDAPURL. Before going further, please add to your question one of the user entry which are not found : the full dn and the attributes present in that entry.

Comment: I tried both

AuthLDAPURL ldaps://realm.domain.local:3269/OU=Users,DC=<domain>,DC=local?uid?sub?(objectClass=*)

and 

AuthLDAPURL ldaps://realm.domain.local:3269/OU=Users,DC=<domain>,DC=local?anr?sub?(objectClass=*)

And both of them failed to work, with the error that my username doesn't exist. Again, if I just use the follwoing it works fine for users with a UID:

AuthLDAPURL ldaps://realm.domain.local:3269

Comment: Will try with samaccountname and userprincpalname now...

Comment: Still no luck with any of those filters.